# Сложности с подключением css к html django

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap

Проблемы с подключением файла css к проекту. Если указать стили внутри html файла, через блок со стилями- все работает хорошо. Но если обратиться к файлу .css проекта, многие стили просто отказываются работать. Я пытаюсь применить этот стиль к изображению. Я попытался поставить !important; думая что это bootstrap не позволяет применить этот стиль, но ничего не вышло. Стиль не применяется.

css-файл:

```
.imgsize{
    width: 350px;
    height:350px;
}
```

HTML-файл:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/tren.css' %}">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'image/h.png' %}">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="der">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="border border-success rounded bg-light text-dark">
      <div class="ml-1">
        <img class="imgsize" src="{% static 'image/1.jpg' %}" alt="Картинка"> //Это не работает
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/alEe3.png

Comment: 1. Для чего подключать бутстрап дважды - один из статик файлов, а второй по cdn? 2. Поставьте свой .css файл первым в подключении. 3. При использовании внешнего статик файла хоть один стиль применяется или файл не виден вовсе?

Comment: Некоторые стили все же применяются. Например, применяется стиль body для проекта.

Comment: К сожалению эти изменения не решили проблему-удалил второй вызов bootstrap и изменил приоритет.

Comment: а если через инспектор посмотреть стили что покажет?